# Babel loader error: rest/spread operator not understood

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, spread-syntax

When I try to run my webpack bundle, I get this console error:

```
BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (113:19)

  111 | 
  112 | const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
> 113 |    <TodoApp todos={...store.getState()}/>,
      |                    ^
  114 |    document.getElementById("root")
  115 | )
  116 |
```

So the spread operator syntax is not understood. However, I have installed the babel-stage-2 preset which I have included in my loaders in `webpack.config.js`, as follows:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
               test: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
               loader: ['babel-loader'],
               query: {
                 presets: debug ? ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre', 'stage-2'] : ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
               }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I also tried installing `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` and adding to `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Still receiving the same error.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you restart webpack after that?

Comment: Getting this error, now trying 2 hours to figure out what the problem is, nothing helps... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `{...store.getState()}` instead of `todos={...store.getState()}`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue with a Vue project.

I have added:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    ["stage-2"]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

in `.babelrc` and tried many things, but nothing seems to work.

As mentioned in [preset-env plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#caveats) in caveats section, you should have at least v6.19.0, mine is v6.23.0 and it still doesn't work.

**EDIT:** I've found the [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219546/webpack-configuration-for-compiling-module-in-node-modules).

**MY SOLUTION**

```
/*
 * additional javascript loader for es6 code in node_modules that have to be transpiled also
 */
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [
        NODE_MODULES + '/vuetify/src'
    ],
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: Config.babel()
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: wow! I've noticed that it works with own code, but not if object spread is applied in node_modules, then it does not work!

Comment: finally I've figured out what was/is the problem: exclude option in the loader prevents babel from compiling code in node_modules! simple as that, spent half a day trying to fix that problem.